# How do I put a WebResponse into a memory stream?

Tags: vb.net

What is the best way to get a file (in this case, a .PDF, but any file will do) from a WebResponse and put it into a MemoryStream?  Using .GetResponseStream() from WebResponse gets a Stream object, but if you want to convert that Stream to a specific type of stream, what do you do?

Answer (score 30):

There is a serious issue with SoloBold's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179676/how-do-i-put-a-webresponse-into-a-memory-stream/179712#179712) that I discovered while testing it. When using it to read a file via an `FtpWebRequest` into a `MemoryStream` it intermittently failed to read the entire stream into memory. I tracked this down to `Peek()` sometimes returning -1 after the first 1460 bytes even though a `Read()` would have succeeded (the file was significantly larger than this).

Instead I propose the solution below:

```
MemoryStream memStream;
using (Stream response = request.GetResponseStream()) {
    memStream = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int byteCount;
    do {
        byteCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        memStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
    } while (byteCount > 0);
}

// If you're going to be reading from the stream afterwords you're going to want to seek back to the beginning.
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// Use memStream as required
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Lawrence. I was getting inconsistent results trying to do this a few other ways.

Comment: When you look at the IL generated (via dotPeek) by the CopyTo(Stream, Int32) method in .net 4.0 you will notice that it generates code with the same pattern but using a single line of code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto(v=vs.100).aspx.

response.CopytTo(memStream,1024);
memStream.Position = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Copied this from the web a year or so ago.

```
//---------- Start HttpResponse
if(objHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //Get response stream
        objResponseStream = objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

        //Load response stream into XMLReader
        objXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(objResponseStream);

        //Declare XMLDocument
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(objXMLReader);

        //Set XMLResponse object returned from XMLReader
        XMLResponse = xmldoc;

        //Close XMLReader
        objXMLReader.Close();
    }

    //Close HttpWebResponse
    objHttpWebResponse.Close();
}
```

Comment: this does not show how to put a WebResponse into a MemoryStream as the original poster asked for.

Answer (score -3):

I found the following at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/eeeefd81-8800-41b2-be63-71acdaddce0e/

```
    Dim request As WebRequest
    Dim response As WebResponse = Nothing
    Dim s As Stream = Nothing
    Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
    Dim file As MemoryStream = Nothing

    Dim uri As New Uri(String.Format("http://forums.microsoft.com/forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2992978&SiteID=1"))
    request = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.Timeout = 10000
    response = request.GetResponse
    s = response.GetResponseStream

    '2 - Receive file as memorystream
    Dim read(256) As Byte
    Dim count As Int32 = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length)
    File = New MemoryStream
    Do While (count > 0)
        File.Write(read, 0, count)
        count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length)
    Loop
    File.Position = 0
    'Close responsestream
    s.Close()
    response.Close()

    '3 - Save file
    fs = New FileStream("c:\test.html", FileMode.CreateNew)
    count = file.Read(read, 0, read.Length)
    Do While (count > 0)
        fs.Write(read, 0, count)
        count = file.Read(read, 0, read.Length)
    Loop
    fs.Close()
    File.Close()
```