# How to set encoding in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, character-encoding, response

I have a problem with encoding, I want to set encoding for example to `HttpWebResponse resp`, everywhere where I look it says something like that `resp.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8`, but in practice that is wrong, because it says that ContentEncoding is a read-only property, please help me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227575/encoding-problem-with-httpwebresponse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to differentiate between two similar-sounding but very different classes:

- [`HttpWebReponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) is the response *received* in code *from* a web request. In other words, you don't get to *set* the data on it, because it was sent by another server.
- [`HttpResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) is the response *your code is sending* from ASP.NET. This is the object you get to write your response data to... and the [`ContentEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contentencoding.aspx) property *is* writable.