# Reading a JavaScript file and outputing it back through HttpHandler

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, twitter, httphandler

You know Twitter is not serving its widget javascript file over https so I decided to serve it through httphandler and so far, I am lost!

Here is what I have done so far :

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {

        using (Stream requestStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {

            Stream outStream = context.Response.OutputStream;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = (int)response.ContentLength, bytes;

            while (len > 0 && (bytes =
                requestStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {

                outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                len -= bytes;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting no error but when I debug the code, I saw that `response.ContentLength` is coming back as `-1`. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

Tried the below code as well to see if it makes any difference and didn't work either:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js");
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.Method = "GET";

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {

        using (Stream requestStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {

            Stream outStream = context.Response.OutputStream;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = (int)response.ContentLength, bytes;

            while (len > 0 && (bytes =
                requestStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {

                outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                len -= bytes;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with the below code. not sure if it is the right way of doing it :

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js");
        request.Accept = "application/javascript";
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Method = "GET";

        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        StreamReader loResponseStream = new
          StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

        string Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

        context.Response.Write(Response);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int bytesProcessed = 0;
        Stream remoteStream = null;
        Stream localStream = null;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js");
    //    request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {

            using (Stream requestStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                localStream = File.Create(@"c:\1.y2yy");

                // Allocate a 1k buffer
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                // Simple do/while loop to read from stream until
                // no bytes are returned
                do
                {
                    // Read data (up to 1k) from the stream
                    bytesRead = requestStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    // Write the data to the local file
                    localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    // Increment total bytes processed
                    bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
                } while (bytesRead > 0);
                localStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: StatusCode and StatusDescription is also coming as OK.

Comment: also for request.ContentType ?

Comment: I already used it for request.ContentType. Doesn't matter what I use for context.Response.ContentType, response ContentLength is coming back as -1.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the problem with different approach : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776631/reading-a-javascript-file-and-outputing-it-back-through-httphandler/7776787#7776787

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code except that you always assume the encoding is 1252. So if you know it is there is no problem. In a perfect world the response of the server will indicate the encoding in its headers. But that is not always the case. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227575/encoding-problem-with-httpwebresponse) for more info on that subject.

I altered your code a litte bit.

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 {           
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/javascript";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
            Encoding enc = String.IsNullOrEmpty(response.CharacterSet) ? 
                Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) : Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc))
            {
                var jsContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(jsContent)) {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
                    context.Response.Write(jsContent);
                }                    
            }
        }
 }
```