# How to fix special Turkish characters in a string?

Tags: c#, encoding, special-characters

I have a string extracted from a url as filename that contains special Turkish characters (çğıİöüş) and they seem wrong. How can I fix it?

```
public static string getFileName(HttpWebResponse response, string url)
{
    var cd = response.Headers["content-disposition"];
    var loc = response.Headers["location"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cd))
    {
        var disp = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(cd);
        return Uri.UnescapeDataString(disp.FileName);
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loc))
        return Path.GetFileName(loc);
    else
        return Path.GetFileName(url);
}
```

**Original String:**

```
y2mate.com - Cengiz Ã–zkan - Suzan Suzi (KÄ±rklar DaÄŸÄ±nÄ±n DÃ¼zÃ¼)_VaW6Mhde9Ko.mp3
```

**Correct string:**

```
y2mate.com - Cengiz Özkan - Suzan Suzi (Kırklar Dağının Düzü)_VaW6Mhde9Ko.mp3
```

Comment: How are you receiving this string? A .Net string as such can handle  these special characters without any problem. The root cause is in the way you retrieve/receive this string value and you'll have to add a [mcve] of this part of your code.

Comment: @Filburt, I have updated adding detail

Comment: Found that in case if: [Encoding trouble with HttpWebResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227575/encoding-trouble-with-httpwebresponse)

Answer (score 4):

It seems you've *mixed* **Win-1254** and **Utf-8** encodings:

```
string original =
  @"y2mate.com - Cengiz Ã–zkan - Suzan Suzi (KÄ±rklar DaÄŸÄ±nÄ±n DÃ¼zÃ¼)_VaW6Mhde9Ko.mp3";

string correct = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1254).GetBytes(original));

// Let's have a look
Console.Write(correct);
```

**Outcome:**

```
y2mate.com - Cengiz Özkan - Suzan Suzi (Kırklar Dağının Düzü)_VaW6Mhde9Ko.mp3
```

Comment: @Olivier Rogier: We have a *special* encoding for Turkish - it's `Win-1254` so I've started from it; `Ã => Ö`, `Ä± => ü` pattern (note `Ä` one an the same character for each Turkish char) is typical for Utf-8 misencoding. So I had a good candidate to try