# Delete a file inside the zip file in SFTP server using C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, sftp, delete-file, zip

Im working with Renci SSH.Net, Is it possible to delete a file inside the ZIP file if I have the file name with me using c# .net core

Answer (score 3):

I think you can not delete a file directly in this zip file in sftp server. But you can download this zip file to a local temp directory and  then you can [delete files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b2b19b4e-aaf8-4126-9cb8-9d20802147f5/delete-a-files-inside-zip-file-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral) in this local temp directory. After the modification you can upload this zip file to your server.

Code taken from the link above (by Denis Radinski):

```
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Desktop\app.zip", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        foreach (var item in archive.Entries)
        {
            if (item.Name.Equals("test.txt"))
            {
                item.Delete();
                break; //needed to break out of the loop
            } // if
        } // foreach
    } // using  
} // using
```

You need to reference `System.IO.Compression.dll`.

Comment: That. Or [as with extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63996368/850848), execute a shell command on the server.